# How to hide TEXT in TextField while clicking outside of TextField in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, textfield

4(Swift4)
I am trying to hide the TextField's text after I end editing the TextField , I tried doing this :

```
textField.isHidden = true
```

But it's job is to hide the TextField , what I want to do is that hide TEXT of the textField after Tapping outside the textField..

EDIT : I want to hide it, I don't want asterisk , I want the text to be invisible and when I click on textField again it should appear the written text again

I tried this :

```
textField.text.isHidden = true
```

It gives me error if I do this way.

Your time and help will be highly appreciated!
Thank You!

Comment: You can save text into another variable and make textfield empty.

Comment: you can change the text color to match its background color

Comment: you can use isSecureTextEntry property when textfield end editing or for hiding text you can store it to somewhere and make texfield empty.

Comment: You want to clear it or just hide?

Comment: I want to hide it, I don't want asterisk , I want the text to be invisible and when I click on textField again it should appear the written text again

Comment: @NoobinSwift you got two answers, you can try any one both are same.

Comment: it's saying you can accept answers in 2 minutes.

Comment: The two minutes is up.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pack the text inside another variable

```
textContent = textField.text
textField.text = ""
```

if you want to hide the content like password set

```
textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
```

//

```
var textContent = ""

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    textContent = textField.text!

    textField.text = ""
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    textField.text = textContent

}
```

Comment: Thank you , really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Take textfield text into a variable and make textfield empty.

```
var textFieldText = textfield.text
textField.text = ""
```